# Is there a shorter way to write a for loop in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax, shorthand

the code is

```
 for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    //do something
 }
```

I use this exact code many times when I program, always starting at 0 and using the interval i++. There is really only one variable that changes (max)

It could not be that much shorter, but considering how much this code is used, it would be quite helpful.

I know in python there is the range function which is much quicker to type.

Comment: Depending on the situation could use a for each loop or [Java 8 streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Comment: If you are using eclipse IDE, there is a short cut for for loops. That way, you can only type a few chars and you are done.

Comment: You could also write your own shorthand function `doInRange(int max, IntConsumer whatToDo)`

Comment: @tobias_k Please write an answer for that. I really like the sound of that pattern.

Comment: static function for every loop? It isnt a good patter believe me!

Comment: I think it just appeals to my love for polymorphism in statically typed languages. And who said they needed to be static functions?

Comment: How do you want to use it across 100 classes? It would be creepy.

Comment: Creepy, but interesting. I can agree that it probably isn't a good idea, but I really want to see it.

Answer (score 12):

When looping through collections, you can use enhanced loops:

```
int[] numbers = 
 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

for (int item : numbers) {
   System.out.println(item);
}
```

Comment: True, but what if I want 1000 iterations? Nobody's going to bother to write out 1000 elements of the array. The number of iterations is also fixed at compile time too. --- If only we had a preprocessor! Just kidding, we might as well swap to C++ for that.

Comment: Well I just used this as an example. The enhanced loop can be used on any collection - the main point is the syntax of for(int item : numbers) as opposed to using something like for(int i = 0; i < collection.size(); i++){} :)

Answer (score 8):

If you use Java 8, you can use `IntStream.range(min, max).foreach(i ->{})`

Comment: The OP specifically asked for a shorter way. By my count, `IntStream.range(min, max).foreach(() -> ` is not shorter than `for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) ` :)

Comment: very funny... It's just better way to use lambda in Java, more readable. Shorter does not mean better.

Comment: I don't personally consider this more readable, either. :) But that gets into the realm of opinion. I've been reading `for` loops for more than 25 years now, so they're pretty second-nature at this point, especially when they follow the standard "0; < max; ++" pattern.

Comment: If you spent 25 years reading `for` loops, you can spend for example 2 days to  get into lambda functions in java and streams. It is really useful.

Comment: They are useful, but using them as replacement for every for loop you have is a very bad idea. As soon as you have even one level of nesting your code gets completely unreadable.

Comment: Oh, I know about them. I don't find what you wrote _less_ readable, I just don't find it _more_ readable, either. And counting chars, it's certainly not shorter.

Comment: @luk2302 That's why you must do external methods :) Cyclomatic complexity concerns `for loops` as well.

Comment: You may regret looping in this way in a multithreaded application.

Comment: There are also parallel streams. In question there is no information about multithreaded environment.

Comment: One advantage of this code is that it protects your "i" variable, discouraging the practice of mutating `i` to affect the state of the loop. It also encourages better naming of `i` (you now only have to write `i` once to create your loop, i.e., as the argument). Thirdly, a non-zero `startIdx` will be seen by a developer more easily.

Answer (score 6):

Since a few people asked for something like this, here are a few things you could do, although whether these are really better is arguable and a matter of taste:

```
void times(int n, Runnable r) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        r.run();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
times(10, () -> System.out.println("Hello, world!"));
```

Or:

```
void times(int n, IntConsumer consumer) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        consumer.accept(i);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
times(10, x -> System.out.println(x+1));
```

Or:

```
void range(int lo, int hi, IntConsumer consumer) {
    for (int i = lo; i < hi; i++) {
        consumer.accept(i);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
range(1, 11, x -> System.out.println(x));
```

These are just a few ideas. Designed thoughtfully, placed in a common library, and used consistently, they could make common, idiomatic code terse yet readable. Used carelessly, they could turn otherwise straightforward code into an unmanageable mess. I doubt any two developers would ever agree on exactly where the lines should be drawn.

Comment: Well the question asked for 'shorter' not 'better' so yes, that would be the perfect solution.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to write shorter for loop.

If "for" loop is the concern, you may find this interesting

```
for(int i = -1; ++i < max;) {
    //do something
 }
```

Notice that the counter increment was done before the comparison with max is done.

Also notice that the index i starts from -1 instead of normal 0.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases max value is unknown (data from files, databases etc.).
For me the best is loading everything to List (ArrayList etc.) and use 
for-each loop. Looping through collections is the best way to short loop syntax in my opinion.

Comment: That's fine if all the data fits in memory, although transforming something that reads from files into something that loads everything to a list first means it *must* all fit in memory, where before it did not necessarily have to.

Comment: Yes, but you can load the data partially, and use them in the for-each loop.

Comment: You mean like a heap?

Answer (score 0):

The for shortcut I thought of is: **for (int i : val)** which works pretty fine for me. Take as an exemple the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; x < val.length; i++)
System.out.print(val[i] + ", ");
```

is equivalent with

```
for (int i : val)
System.out.print(i + ", ");
```

After having some research, I found this 
[link](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/javacode/codeSamples/EnhancedFor.java) with examples for the *EnhancedFor*. This kind of writing the for loop looks very similar to the way of writing a [for in Linux Bash](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/).

Comment: Not available for java.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way for List's

Normal Mode:

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a","b","c","d","e","f"});
for (int i=0;i<myList.size();i++){
    System.out.println(myList.get(i));
}
```

Short Mode 1:

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a","b","c","d","e","f"});
myList.forEach((node)->{
    System.out.println(node);
});
```

Short Mode 2:

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a","b","c","d","e","f"});
for(String node: myList){
   System.out.println(node);
}
```

Comment: Even shorter is: `myList.forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Of course, it depends on the number of lines in the loop